# SharePoint 2013 farm restore error: The specified component exists

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, error, restore

**Overall context:** Moving a Hyper-V VM 2012 R2 single server TFS system w/ SharePoint to a new domain.

**Immediate task:** Backup SharePoint content to be able to restore content if there are problems with the move.

**Some relevant actions taken:**

- PCConfigUI.exe was successfully executed
- A successful full farm backup was created

**Immediate problem:** I tried an immediate restore after the successful backup.  The restore operation reported a completion with 5 errors.  I'd like to eliminate the errors if possible.

The following are the objects that reported errors; the error follows after this list.  Everything else reported completed:

- In section SharePoint - 80.

  - Object WSS_Content
- In section Shared Services

  - Object Secure Store Service
  - Object Secure_Store_Service_DB_{long guid}
  - Object Excel Services Application
- In Section Shared Service Proxies

  - Object Secure Store Service

In each case the reported error on the Central Administration page is the same as what's in the log file, and it is:

"Content failed in event OnRestore. For more information, see the spbackup.log or sprestore.log file located in the backup directory. 
SPException: The specified component exists. You must specify a name that does not exist."

I have no idea what to do with this.

Should I only be restoring portions of the backup?  If so, which portions?

Answer (score 1):

check couple of things.

- Make sure database name's are different or
- not already exist on the SQL server
- make sure SQL server versions are same.

BTW, i highly recommend in your mentioned scenrio simply move the Content rather performing a restore.

- Install and configure new farm on new domain
- Create and configure the Web application, Service Application etc.
- Now backup and restore the Content DBs to new sql server and mount to SharePoint.

check this https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/install/sharepoint/move-sharepoint-new-hardware

Comment: I have begun to think a new farm in the new domain might be my best approach, but needed someone to nudge me that way; thanks.  I'm also  thinking I will create a single separate dedicated server SharePoint install instead of the single server system currently in place. Regarding your recommendation to simply move Content, in principle it makes sense. I probably need a little more information for those steps.  Do you have some favorite guidance links about working with the DBs for this?  As well as creating the Web/Service apps for the TFS connection?

Comment: The part about the restore failing several objects bothers me because I'm simply backing up, and then restoring right back into the same farm.  I don't see why one would have to change anything.  Does the Central Admin backup tool allow illegal backups and saves?  Was I supposed to do an overwrite?  Or am I supposed to be backing up SQL databases instead of using SharePoint backup?

Comment: I just added link.

Comment: are you using the same sql server on new domain?

Comment: The plan was to move the single server over, so I guess the answer to your question in that case is yes.  I was hoping to bring the server up in totality in the new domain.  But if I have to abandon that & go with building metal up, then no, it would be a new SQL server.  Also an update: I did get a successful restore! I had to click the radio button on the final restore setup page that does an overwrite.  So, I guess technically that's the answer to my question posted here, but your advice is very valuable to me and I appreciate it.  I will continue to follow up on this.